# Prometheus on GCP Kubernetes cluster error "no such host"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to setup Prometheus on GCP Kubernetes cluster. I followed [this tutorial](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/).

I have the deployment pod running.
Now I am trying to access the Prometheus dashboard by port forwarding as shown in the blog.
But the page is inaccessible.
I tried to debug and checked the logs of the deployment pod and found that there is an error there.

```
ts=2021-12-31T06:49:42.109Z caller=notifier.go:526 level=error component=notifier alertmanager=http://alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093/api/v2/alerts count=1 msg="Error sending alert" err="Post \"http://alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093/api/v2/alerts\": dial tcp: lookup alertmanager.monitoring.svc on <IP>:53: no such host"
```

Comment: this is realted to alert manager check if you alert manager running or not first.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Can you provide a little more details about your setup ? What have you tried already ?

Comment: I have created a kubernetes cluster on GKE and followed the same steps as in the link (blog)

Comment: So - you are stuck at the `kubectl port-forward prometheus-monitoring-3331088907-hm5n1 8080:9090 -n monitoring` (taken from linked tutorial) command ? If so please provide exact command 
 and error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you're getting may be due to your cluster configuration or general setup.

I've gone step-by-step over the tutorial you linked and everything worked - I could connect to the home page. I didn't go further but I will describe all the steps below.

1. I created new GKE cluster using [autopilot feature](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview).
2. Then I ran fallowing commands in the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) (but you can use any other system with `kubectl` installed):

```
ACCOUNT=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.account)')
kubectl create clusterrolebinding owner-cluster-admin-binding \
    --clusterrole cluster-admin \
    --user $ACCOUNT
```

3. Then I cloned the Git repo `git clone https://github.com/bibinwilson/kubernetes-prometheus`
4. Created the namespace: `kubectl create namespace monitoring`
5. Created `clusterRole.yaml` file with following content:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/proxy
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/metrics"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: monitoring
```

6. Created a role `kubectl create -f clusterRole.yaml`
7. Created a file `congi-map.yaml` with fallowing content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server-conf
  labels:
    name: prometheus-server-conf
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  prometheus.rules: |-
    groups:
    - name: devopscube demo alert
      rules:
      - alert: High Pod Memory
        expr: sum(container_memory_usage_bytes) > 1
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: slack
        annotations:
          summary: High Memory Usage
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
      evaluation_interval: 5s
    rule_files:
      - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules
    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - scheme: http
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - "alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093"

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
          action: keep
          regex: default;kubernetes;https

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics     
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
      
      - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080']

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
          action: replace
          target_label: __scheme__
          regex: (https?)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          target_label: __address__
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_name
```

8. Created a config map `kubectl create -f config-map.yaml`
9. Created `prometheus-deployment.yaml` file with following content:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - "--storage.tsdb.retention.time=12h"
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 500M
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: prometheus-server-conf
  
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          emptyDir: {}
```

10. Created deployment `kubectl create  -f prometheus-deployment.yaml`
11. Checked it:

```
wb@cloudshell:~$ kubectl get deployments --namespace=monitoring
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
prometheus-deployment   1/1     1            1           145m
```

12. Got the pod name:

```
wb@cloudshell:~$ kubectl get pods --namespace=monitoring
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
prometheus-deployment-7f57368-bk4   1/1     Running   0          146m
```

13. Forwarded ports `kubectl port-forward prometheus-deployment-7f57368-bk4 8080:9090 -n monitoring`
14. In second window I opened up another shell and ran: `curl http://localhost:8080` which resulted in:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb-project-1)$ curl http://localhost:8080
<a href="/graph">Found</a>.
```

This means that the page is accessible and working - you can try to go ahead and follow my steps and if something goes not as expected just provide detailed information where you got stuck and what's the error.